# Android 6.0 Chrome upload file and not Firefox

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, upload

something make me crazy, I have to develop a web site which will be use on Android tablet. I've got to perform a picture uploading from tablet browser to server. I got source code which works on Chrome but not on FF. The thing which make me crazy is ... this sources works with FF on PC.

This is html sources:

```
    <form action="http://XXXXX/uploadPicture" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"  accept="capture=camera"/>
    </form>
```

The error return by FF is the target page can't be read. It suggest that the file was deleted, move or file properties don't allow to acces to it.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
accept="capture=camera"
```

it should be

```
accept="image/*" capture="camera"
```

Comment: If you put : accept="image/*", you can't access to camera directly. You have only acces to picture already taken by the camera (even if you put capture="camera").